# Session doesn't start when correct login credentials are given

Tags: php, sql, session

Alright, SO. After about five hours of sifting through potential duplicates and applying would-be solutions to my project and even downloading a PHP IDE to make sure that my syntax is all nice and tidy for everyone.. I am finally at the point where I need some advice.

My two problems (which may be related):

When someone logs in, successfully with the test parameters I have stored in the DB, they are not redirected (maybe my if statement is not correct?)

When the page loads without first attempt, my "wrong password - username combination" message is displaying. I'm fairly certain as to *why* but not too sure *how to fix it*.

```
<?php session_start(); // this line of code has been added by the instruction of a comment.
    if(isset($submit)) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    }
$con = mysqli_connect("***","***","***","***"); 
$S_username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $username);
$S_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $password);

if(mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$S_username' AND `password` = '$S_password'");

if(!$sql) {
die(mysqli_error($con)) ; 
}

$check_again = mysqli_num_rows($sql);

    if($check_again == 1) {
    session_start(); // this line of code has been deleted 
    $_SESSION['logged in'] = TRUE;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $S_username;
    header("Location: http://terrythetutor.com/submitvideo.php");
    }
    else {
    echo "Your username and password combination was not recognised. Please try again." ;
    }

?>
<html>
<head> 
<title>Login Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
    <?php include_once 'googleanalytics.php'; ?>
<body>
<a href="http://terrythetutor.com">
    <div class="banner"> </div>
</a>
<?php include 'menu.php'; ?>
<h1 align="center">Please login to access restricted files</h1>
</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>
<div align="center">
<form action = "login.php" method = "post">

Username: <input type = "text" name = "username"></br></br>

Password: <input type = "password" name = "password"></br></br>

<input type = "submit" value = "Login" name="submit">

</form>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Any and all feedback is welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: Try putting `session_start();` as your first line of code under your opening `<?php` tag.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I added the 'session_start();' but it didn't change anything, unfortunately. Should I remove the session_start from my if statement?

Comment: Yes, only have the one if you're going to put it on top. It can't be anywhere else (unless you have different conditional statements). Plus, if you're using other files with this, they also need it in there. I.e.: `includes` and `menus` etc.

Comment: @Fred-ii- The `session_start();` needs to _also_ be inside of my included menus and footers? 

Also, I'm noticing that when I login I'm not being redirected and I can't seem to find the error.

Comment: Yes, `session_start();` needs to be inside ALL pages that are using the same session, and in the same spot/conditional statement. If putting it at the top didn't work **AND** it's not inside your other files (using the same session), then place it in there as well. You can only have the ONE instance of `session_start();` inside each file, not two.

Comment: Although, it's always best to just put it at the top (only), and nowhere else. Sessions inside conditional statements can be tricky, so try putting it on top only and see if that works. Keep me posted.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you for all of your help! I managed to resolve the issue with your guidance.

Comment: Glad I could be of help. However I was scratching my head to figure out why you accepted an answer to which it was already told by me, from an original comment made 10 minutes prior to the answer below.

Comment: @Fred-ii- This is only because I'm fairly new to SO and its norms. I am unaware of how to accept a comment as an answer :/.

Comment: It's ok, don't sweat it. However for future questions, should you post any, is that if someone else besides myself helps you out and a comment solves your problem, then the right thing to do is to either ask the commenter if you'd like him/her to make it an answer in order to close the question. When someone spends a lot of time helping someone out, and someone else comes along who read the comments, will immediately put in an answer, for all the wrong reasons. You'll soon differentiate the good guys from the bad. Now, the important thing here is that your problem was solved. Welcome to SO. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `session_start();` only once and at the top ..

Comment: Thank you, I have just changed that by the instruction of Fred-ii-. However, I'm noticing that when I put in the login credentials, it doesn't even redirect to another page. Any idea why?

Comment: use this article [link](http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html) or this article [link](http://php.about.com/od/finishedphp1/ss/php_login_code_2.htm)